# Repaint of panel

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, panel

My problem is that I have a panel in panel. Inside i have the `AutoScroll` property set to true. When I open a new window this panel is scrolled to begining.

I do that, I save the position before open new window, and I set it after close it. It works but it jumps to the beginning and then back to my position.

Comment: WebForms? aps .net? Could you post some code to explain it better?

Comment: I'm suspecting WinForms here.

Answer (score 5):

The AutoScrollPosition property is a bit funny. When you read it, it will return the current scroll offset, but when you assign it you will need to invert the values:

```
private static Point GetAutoScrollPosition(Panel panel)
{
    return panel.AutoScrollPosition;
}

private static void SetAutoScrollPosition(Panel panel, Point position)
{
    panel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-position.X, -position.Y);
}
```

Now you can retrieve the current position and set it like so:

```
Point pos = GetAutoScrollPosition(myPanel);
SetAutoScrollPosition(myPanel, pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `autoscroll` to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

I do something lik You wrote

_scrollPozition = -(pnlMain.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Delete: ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
dgvClendar.Focus();

private void pnlMain_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (pnlMain.AutoScrollPosition.Y == 0)
        {
            pnlMain.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, _scrollPozition);
            _scrollPozition = 0;
        }
    }
```

on paint it is set, but if you look everything is moved for a moment. I need to block this scroll to begin, or block painting, and repaint after scroll to current position.

Comment: You would not want to do this in the Paint event; it is raised over and over again as soon as the some part of the panel needs to be repainted. Assign the position during Form_Load or some other event that occurs before the form is visible.